# Create and custom one UIButton for multiple data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, reusability

I have an array of content as follow:

array = [Name1,Name2,Name3...]

and I want to display these content on the label of the button. The problem is it will be hardcore if my array have many item and I dont want to create so many button like that. So please anyone can help me to findout the way to generate one common button instance for these data. Like if my array have 2 item, the view will display 2 buttons and so on... THank you very much!

P/s: Problem solved with @Janmenjaya answer, here is my code, still have a little bit stuck with y position.

```
func displayFileList() {
    for i in 0..<fileIdList.count {
        let yRef : CGFloat = 35
        let title = String(fileIdList.indexOf(i))
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yRef * CGFloat(i), width: 919, height: 30))
        button.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.fileButtonContainView.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array and create the button programmatically with dynamic title based on the array contents.

Follow the sample code

**Sample code snippet :**

```
    arrData = NSMutableArray();

    arrData.addObject("Test0");
    arrData.addObject("Test1");
    arrData.addObject("Test2");
    arrData.addObject("Test3");
    arrData.addObject("Test4");

    var yRef : CGFloat = 100

    for i in 0..<arrData.count{

        let title = arrData.objectAtIndex(i);

        let btn = UIButton(type: .Custom);
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, yRef, 100, 40);
        btn.setTitle(title as? String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();
        self.view.addSubview(btn);

        yRef += CGRectGetHeight(btn.frame) + 10;
    }
```

Output : 
[image]

Hope it helps

Happy coding ...

Comment: just a little bit, when i set the title of my button, it wont display the text. it displayed the warning as follow: "Cast from 'Index?' to unrelated type 'String' always fails'. It seem like some problem from type converting

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen show me your code. May be you are not keeping string in the array, You may be keeping custom objects in the array.

Comment: i solved, the problem come from the yRef variable, but now i want to put them in one UIview with height = 90, so that i can display 3 button with height = 30 fit exactly with the view. But i just havent solve it. Here is my code:

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen I just noticed you have taken the yRef inside the for loop, you need to take that out side the for loop, or else each button will be on same y position, so that you can n't able to see all button

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen I just noticed you have taken the yRef inside the for loop, you need to take that out side the for loop, or else each button will be on same y position, so that you can n't able to see all button

Comment: thank you, i got it. But the title still display not same as my array. Here is my array: var fileIdList = [1,2,3].
But the button title displayed: nil, 1, 2

Comment: You are fetching the index of element present in array, but we need to fetch the element present in that index from the array. replace that line with this one            let title =  arrTemp[i]

Comment: You are fetching the index of element present in array, but we need to fetch the element present in that index from the array. replace that line with this one            let title =  arrTemp[i]